# Is the dot of Shin and Sin explained as a part of Nikkud?

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, vowels-nekudot

Following [the question about שכר ושכר](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103755/alcoholic-drinks-and-reward-are-both-%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8),

Shin and Sin letters have a little dot that [does not have a name](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95#%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%99%22%D7%9F) and is used exclusively to differentiate between them (diacritic).

I read books about the spiritual meaning of different Nikkud signs but I don't recall that dot.

Is the dot mentioned by interpreters as a part of Hebrew Nikkud? If not, then why not?

Comment: See how yeshaya 5.5 is quoted in yerushalmi Bava Kama 1.1

Comment: Rav Hirsch *seems* to learn that Shin and Sin are two different letters, but because they can be exchanged for one another exegetically they indicate differing degrees of intensity in meaning.