# PTIJ: Are there other ritually demanded drinks?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Rituals and laws, in certain situations, are predicated on the presence of certain drinks. The four I can think of are

1. the test for an adulterous woman which requires the use of [Soda](http://www.tfdixie.com/parshat/naso/014.htm) Water
2. any proceedings which require testimony and thus demand an ade (much like the case where one must testify that an etrog is not [grafted](https://esrogdepot.com/pages/halacha), a case which involves lemonade, or the ben sorer or moreh situation where one can claim that what was [drunk](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/11698.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) was not wine via a [Grapeade](https://farmerowned.com/featuredRecipe/1415/Grapeade/)).
3. The method of punishing those who were involved in cheit ha'egel as those people had to drink [ground](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.20?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) calf-ee.
4. Levites can take certain [gifts](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.18.31?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), ferment them into [sheichar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103755/alcoholic-drinks-and-reward-are-both-%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8)/alcohol and drink them.

Are there other drinks which are demanded by ritual?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89686/16354

Answer (score 19):

1. By the [Parah Adumah](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.19.1-10?lang=bi&aliyot=0), once the process was complete, one should drink [Red Bull](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Red%20bull&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjm0afFpu7uAhXa_IUKHcWBDjYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Red%20bull&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQQzIFCAAQsQMyBwgAELEDEEMyBQgAELEDMgUIABCxAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADIFCAAQsQMyAggAOgQIIxAnOggIABCxAxCDAVCcoRtYyqwbYOqtG2gAcAB4AIABQIgB0AOSAQE4mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=fKwrYOajC9r5lwTFg7qwAw&bih=775&biw=1536)
2. Halachically, if one sees a place where a miracle occurred he is required to make a bracha (refer to [SA OC 218:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.218.4?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi)). What is less well known, is the need to also drink the appropriate beverage afterwards - [Nes-tea](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Nestea&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj0_tabqO7uAhUMYBoKHUV5BxQQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Nestea&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BAgjECc6CAgAELEDEIMBOgUIABCxAzoHCAAQsQMQQ1D51wdY2N4HYNjfB2gAcAB4AIABOogBxQKSAQE2mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=Pa4rYLTsLYzAacXynaAB&bih=775&biw=1536)
3. When the fruit trees come into blossom not only do we say the appropriate bracha ([SA OC 226](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.226.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), but we acknowledge this growth by taking a [Bud](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bud%20beer&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiL2afZv-7uAhUMTBoKHVAoDmAQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=bud%20beer&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIIxAnOgoIABCxAxCDARBDUL4WWJofYIkgaABwAHgAgAFCiAH3AZIBATSYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=3cYrYMt2jJhp0NC4gAY&bih=775&biw=1536)

---

It is worth noting that there are not only drinks required for rituals, but even for more generic scenarios.

[Pirkei Avos 1:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.4?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) famously writes:

> יוֹסֵי בֶן יוֹעֶזֶר אִישׁ צְרֵדָה אוֹמֵר, יְהִי בֵיתְךָ בֵית וַעַד לַחֲכָמִים, וֶהֱוֵי מִתְאַבֵּק בַּעֲפַר רַגְלֵיהֶם, **וֶהֱוֵי שׁוֹתֶה בְצָמָא אֶת דִּבְרֵיהֶם**
>
> Yose ben Yoezer used to say: let thy house be a house of meeting for the Sages and sit in the very dust of their feet, **and drink in their words with thirst**.

It therefore follows that we should be drinking directly from their Torah. For those that subscribe to the Soloveitchik model, they should obviously be drinking [Brisk](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=brisk&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjIn-nGpe7uAhUNyRoKHS5MD9MQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=brisk&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQQzIFCAAQsQMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoECCMQJzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BwgAELEDEENQob4OWKfDDmD3xA5oAHAAeACAAT2IAZoCkgEBNZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=cqsrYMieOI2Sa66YvZgN&bih=775&biw=1536). For everyone else there is [Focus](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Focus%20Water&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiEmOjYqO7uAhUCWBoKHUN-DzQQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Focus%20Water&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAFEB4yBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQBRAeOgQIIxAnOgQIABBDOgUIABCxA1CLqQhYmrcIYNq5CGgAcAB4AIABYYgB2QWSAQIxMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=va4rYMTFOoKwacP8vaAD&bih=775&biw=1536).

On Shavuos, there are those who upon hearing the reading of Matan Torah where we formally became a nation as we received the Torah at Har Sinai, make a point of drinking some [Mountain Jew](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mountain%20Dew&sxsrf=ALeKk00g0trGxLjSlsr8AlemiXc4gTRhlg:1613546988998&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV6e34svDuAhUQEcAKHfnKCAAQ_AUoAXoECBAQAw&biw=1536&bih=775).

Additionally, in the current pandemic we should be doing our *hishtadlus* to ensure we help keep safe, and keep others safe as well. As such, we should all be making sure we gain the necessary antibodies in the fight against the virus. The natural choice is that we all drink in [Corona](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=corona%20beer&sxsrf=ALeKk008NzxM4Erb-EPG17frw8_SPlxbaA:1613474551607&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDloKMpe7uAhVnVBUIHZ0UA60Q_AUoAnoECAkQBA&biw=1536&bih=775).

For those on Shidduchim, a potential kallah is always on the lookout for a real [smoothie](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sca_esv=379377774f7d6d8c&sxsrf=ACQVn09rA1OteFoo--uC1y75FvVoGtBnAA:1710713651723&q=smoothie&tbm=isch&source=lnms&prmd=ivmnbtz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkxJf8qPyEAxWwXUEAHVCDDz0Q0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1498&bih=746&dpr=1.25).

Finally, (hat tip to @Yaakov5777) we are charged to fully engross ourselves in Hashem's mitzvos - "[וחי בהם](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.18.5?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)" - this job is made infinitely easier when enjoying same Chai Tea

Comment: By the same logic, are we obligated to drink Zima on the z'manim?  And would it be a Torah or a rabbinical obligation?

Comment: Well done, plus one!

Comment: Thanks @רבותמחשבות

Comment: what about chai tea?

Comment: Good shout @Yaakov5777 - added! :-)